# spring mvc properties - java.io.FileNotFoundException: config.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have created a properties file and trying to access this in my spring DAO class file, but am getting **"java.io.FileNotFoundException: config.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)"**. I have tried different scenarios to put the file in different folder/locations but getting same issue. Can anybody please help me on this. Below is the code and structure details,

In DAO class,

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("config.properties");
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(reader);
```

I tried to put the "config.properties" file under **src/main/resources** and also under `WEB-INF/`. My DAO class is in `src/main/java/com/test/dao`
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why aren't you letting Spring load the properties file instead? Assuming it is in `src/main/resources` just add a `@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")` to your configuration file (or `context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties"` when using XML). Then you can either use `@Value` on properties in your dao to get access to them or use the `Environment`.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the file in *src/main/resources* where its most appropriate and change the way you retrieve it into:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("config.properties").getFile());
FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
```

Comment: Great! Thx Deinum/Maciej its working now, Maciej codes did the job. @Deinum : I hope there is no issue if we didn't used to retrieve via spring properties?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to read from a property file, the best practice would be to keep it in the *src/main/resources* folder , which is the default location for property files as per spring . The  you can either use annotations to read the values in the property file, which spring will automatically read and inject.

By using @value annotation:

```
@Value( "${jdbc.url:aDefaultUrl}" )
private String jdbcUrl;
```

Note: Here you can also specify the default value.

By using xml configuration:

```
<bean id="dataSource">
<property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
<bean>
```

By using the @PropertySource annotation :

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties")
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {
//...
}
```

Here you can provide the keys to be mapped in the class and it will get mapped automatically to the fields.

you can also specify multiple property files like :

```
@PropertySources({
@PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties"),
@PropertySource("classpath:bar.properties")
})
```

Note : Keep in mind for this to work the property file should have an extension like *.properties* and values in property file should follow the property file convention.